# AJAX Call with Large Result Set Writing to DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I am writing an application that allows a user to dynamically select which columns they want to pull from our database (all public internal data) as well as customize their logic (WHERE Clause).

The result sets from these queries can be anything from a 10 records to our whole table of over 35,000 records.

On load of the result page, I trigger an AJAX function which runs the query that user has chosen and this triggers to stored procedure to run the query. This data is then passed to the AJAX success function and rendered to the DOM so it can be manipulated, exported etc.

--

**The Issue:**

When people choose to download the entire table (not often but certain departments have a need), we are having timeout issues which can be expected.

I am trying to find out where the bottle neck is to try and improve the experience.

When I run the query directly on the database for the 35,000 record result set, it takes about 12 seconds over VPN so I don't think the issue is with the database it self.

[image]

You can see in the image above where the timeout happened on the POST call.

I am trying to understand how the process flows for fetching / writing data to the DOM. Is the connection that is fetching the data from the database timing out or do we successfully have that data but we are timing out trying to write the 35,000 table rows?

**Example Code:**

```
var output = '';

$.ajax({
    url: "api/fetchDashboardRender",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        dashboardID: dashboardID
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    },
    success: function(data) {
       // Example .. Loop over the data in the result set
       $(data).each(function(){
          // Append each table row to a variable
          output += '';
       }); 
       // Once done, append the variable to the DOM
       $('#results').append(output);

    }

});
```

**Questions:**

While I understand there is no need to write that much data to the DOM, there are reasons they want it done and I am following instruction.

1. Does the success function of an AJAX call include the DOM
   manipulation or is it it successful once the data has been retrieved
   from the source?
2. Is there a better way to approach this type of situation outside of making multiple calls in a paginated approach for batches of data?
3. Can you help me identify the main bottle neck here as to where things are being hung up?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The timeouts appear to be unrelated to how you are sending the ajax requests and the success callback. Instead, the network/server is ending the request. Not a whole lot you can do client-side to fix this unless the server supports pagination.

Comment: @KevinB - I created a blank page with a PHP call directly to the stored procedure and ran it. It took 55 seconds but it completed. I didn't render anything to the page but the call finished. Is the success call staying open while the DOM is being written to that may be exceeding some type of timeout?

Comment: You aren't even getting to the point where the DOM begins getting interacted with. jquery hasn't received the response.

Comment: @KevinB - Forgive the multiple questions, just trying to understand. If the Database server is returning the data on the PHP call, why would it be any different for the AJAX call? The image in the OP got to about 4 mins before timing out and the direct PHP to stored procedure had the data within a minute.

Comment: because when dealing with HTTP, timeouts can happen at any stage in the process. The DB can timeout, the connection between the DB and PHP can timeout, the connection between PHP and the webserver can timeout, between the webserver and the network, network and proxy, network and you, the browser itself can timeout a connection, etc.

Comment: The only fool proof way to reduce the likelyhood of a timeout is to make the requests smaller.